# Bootstrap: Banner must have fixed width of 1350px and center aligned after 1400px width with background color on both the sides

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a banner inside a fluid container, but I want the banner width to be fixed after 1400px width and center aligned. I dont want it to stretch more than that. Is there a simple way to do this ?

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid blue_back">
<div class="container-fluid ">
   <div class="row banner-content">


        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="row nav1 search search_bar1" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header navbar_search">

                  <form class="navbar-form form1 "  role="search">
                     <select  class="selectbox1 form_input" >
                        <option> Search in Hospitals </option>
                        <option> Search in Packages </option>
                        <option> Search in Diagnostics </option>
                        <option> Search in  Doctors </option>
                        <option> Search in  Tests </option>
                    </select>

                     <input type="text" class="form_input" placeholder="Type Hospital Name"  name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                     <input type="text" class="form_input" placeholder="Type Location" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                     <input type="text" class="form_input" placeholder="Type Speciality" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
                     <button class="form_button"   type="submit"></button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                    </div>        
             </div>
          <div class="row social_media aa">

             <input type="submit" value="Book Appointment" class="appointment_book_home" />
           <input type="submit" value="" class="search_book_home"/>
           <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled social_media_icons">
               <li><a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png"/> </a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><img src="images/google.png"/> </a></li>
               <li><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png"/> </a></li>
           </ul>

       </div>
          <div class="row statistics_home">
       <div class="col-xs-4 dashed_border">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 stat_image">
                    <img src="images/List/hospital_icon_menu.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="statistics_head"> 800+ </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="statistics_text"> Health Centres </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-xs-4 dashed_border">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 stat_image">
                    <img src="images/List/hospital_icon_menu.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="statistics_head"> 800+ </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="statistics_text"> Packages and Tests </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 dashed_border" style="border: none;">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-2 stat_image">
                    <img src="images/List/hospital_icon_menu.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="statistics_head"> 800+ </h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                    <h4 class="statistics_text"> Doctors </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

   </div>
</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS

```
.banner-content {
   background: url('http://localhost:8383/Buzz_HomePage/images/homeimage1.jpg') no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;
   height: 290px;
   }
```

Comment: What width should the banner be at 1399px? Will it be 1399? So it will jump back down to 1350 after you go 1px wider?

Comment: https://github.com/marcvannieuwenhuijzen/BootstrapXL/blob/master/BootstrapXL.css (adjust widths with search & replace)

Comment: What have you tried? Consider creating a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to understand your problem better.

Comment: @Brendan Hi Brendan, I want it to have the max-width of 1350 .. anything screen width above that it should start aligning center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly,  you should add this css:

```
.banner-content {
 width:100%;
 max-width:1350px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you need more help, you might try posting a JSfiddle.

Comment: Thank you soo much.. Works beautifully .. But for all screen widths. I want it to take the full screen width for any screen below 1350px

Comment: Depends on your setup, but you could just try adding width:100%.  This will make it 100% of the parent container.  You are allowed to combine width and max-width to achieve this.